# How do you add someone else's project to your current project?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use this color dialog written by someone else in my program but I don't know how to integrate it. I'm very new to C# so I am not really sure what I'm doing.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33001/WPF-A-Simple-Color-Picker-With-Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that for third-party code, you do not integrate their source code directly into your own project, but an assembly reference to the compiled foreign code. This makes it easier to separate your code from third-party code, and update the third-party code later on if a new version becomes available.

So this is roughly what you do.

1. First, create an assembly from the third-party code (the color picker source code):

   1. Download the source code.
   2. Open the Visual Studio solution (`.sln`) hopefully present in the download.
   3. Create a Release build. (This might require you first changing the build configuration to *Release* via the *Build* menu in Visual Studio.)
   4. After a successful build, there should now be the color picker DLL in the `bin\Release` folder.

2. Next, add the created assembly (`.dll`) into your own project and reference it:

1. Put a copy of that DLL into your own solution/project's directory.
2. In your own project, add an assembly reference to that assembly (via the *Solution Explorer* window's *References* node's context menu).

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in the solution explorer, right click on `References`, click on `Add reference`, select `Browse` and add it.

Answer (score 0):

To add an existing project to a solution:

1. In Solution Explorer, select the solution or the solution folder that you want to add a project    to.
2. Right click, select Add and then choose Existing Project.
3. Select the project you want to add to the solution and then click Open.

To add an assembly reference to an existing

1. Right click on References in your project in Solution Explorer
2. Select Add Reference.
3. Select Browse and navigate to the assembly